# How can I do some cleanup right before an Android app is quitting?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-activity

Is there some sort of onTerminate() method where I can do some cleanup (I want to clear some SharedPreferences) when my Android app is terminating?

I have an Activity that is keeping a running average of a few numbers, that I'm storing in a SharedPreference. I want this average to last while the app is running (the user can move between different activities) so I can't clear it on onDestroy() for that particular activity. I need to be able to clear it once the app is about to quit.

How can I do this?

Comment: Considering that there's no guarantee that you get any event other than `onPause()` before the app is closed.. does android support `Runtime.addShutdownHook` and does it work as you'd expect?

Comment: Do you want your running average to not be clear as long as at least one activity is alive? If you hit the home button, should the average be cleared immediately or only when the os finally kills your activities? If the user just re starts your main activity can you clear the preferences then? If you only want these averages to last while your app is running, have you thought about a service instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So android doesn't really have a concept of an app being "finished". Unfortunently there is nothing synonymous to "onTerminate()". Is there some criteria by which you can decide when to clear your running average?

Comment: I guess if the app goes to the Home screen I can consider it "terminated", though there are edge cases that can deem this invalid, I am willing to make exceptions...

Comment: Actually there does exist an `onTerminate` method in `android.app.Application` class .. however it is useless in this scenario since it is only called in emulated process environments and never on actual devices.

Answer (score 2):

I've not tried this, but here's what I would do:

- As Alex mentioned in the comment to original question, use a `Service` to share the app-wide state between `Activities`.
- Whenever you move between `Activities`, bind to the service from the "new" activity, and unbind from the "old" one. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#CoordinatingActivities) to understand how to coordinate activities.
- If you follow this properly, you can ensure that at least one `Activity` is always bound to the `Service` as long as your app is running; and that all Activities are unbound when the app is no longer running - at which point your service's `onDestroy()` is called. This is where you perform your cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SharedPreference.Editor` to remove the preferences, and commit. Here's a link for you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: That's not at all what he's asking about.

Comment: I know how to remove the preference, I just need to figure out WHEN to remove it.