# When and how to stop Services

Tags: android, service

I'm searching for a way to cleanly shutdown my Android services. They should run as long as at least one of my activities are there.

Is there a way on getting an event when the whole application is destroyed and not only a single activity? This way it would be easy to handle the shutdown of the services. But I didn't found such intents or events.

So I thought of two possibilites to handle that but they seem a bit strange to me:

1. Write a service which counts the open and closed activities. To implement that I would have to add the activityStarted and activityClosed notification calls in the onPause and onCreate methods. When every activity got paused or destroyed my watcher service would stop the running services and eventually itself.
2. Use the DB to write the count of the activities out when onPause or onCreate is called. The first activity which notices on its onPause that there are no other activities starts the service shutdown procedure.

What would you do?

Answer (score 1):

Extend Service class and implement ServiceConnected to your activites.
Then bind and calculate OnBind()/Unbind() service.

Comment: +1 - sound good, just waiting if there other ways but that's a solution candidate.

Answer (score 0):

When you "hand over" from one `Activity` to the next, you need to ensure that you `unbind()` your `Service` from the "old" `Activity` and `bind()` to your `Service` from the "new" one. [This thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7924855/570930) deals with something similar. Pay special attention to the link in this answer that refers to the "Coordinating Activities" piece of the Android documentation.